# How to connect to a remote Windows machine to change mdb file using python?

Tags: python, wmi

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a script that connects to a remote windows machine and change mdb file there. I can’t figure out how to work with the WMI library.

When I need to change mdb file (Access database) on my machine, I just use pyodbc connect. For example like this:

connStr = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
                             r'DBQ=C:\Komax\Data\Topwin\DatabaseServer.mdb;')

cursor = connStr.cursor()

But now I need to run code on my machine so that it modifies the file (mdb) on the other machine. It seems like I have to use this code below to connect to remote machine, but I don't know what to do next, how to use connection. Please, help me to solve the problem :)

ip = "192.168.18.74"

username = "admin"

password = "komax"

from socket import *

try:

```
print("Establishing connection to %s" % ip)

connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)

print("Connection established")
```

except wmi.x_wmi:

```
print("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")
```